# Prevent a drop at a particular item in the list in jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

The `isValidTarget` allows "only" for checking if the whole target container is dropable but I can't use it for a particular item in the container. Or I'm wrong?

How can I retrieve id of the target item to be dropped at in `isValidTarget` in order to use it for preventing a drop in my customized `isValidTarget` function?

This real situation from my project will better clarify my case.

```
<ol>
<li id="1" class="do-not-drop-here">item1</li>
<li id="2" class="do-not-drop-here">item2</li>
<li id="3">item3</li>
<li id="4">item4</li>
<li id="5">item5</li>
<li id="6">item6</li>
<li id="7" class="do-not-drop-here">item7</li>
<li id="8" class="do-not-drop-here">item8</li>
<li id="9" class="do-not-drop-here">item9</li>
<li id="10">item10</li>
<li id="11">item11</li>
<li id="12">item12</li>
</ol>
```

I don't want any item to be inserted between 1 and 2 nor between 7,8 and 9.

Comment: Johnny Sortable javascript library - can be found here: http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Comment: Hey @Bill-the-Lizard, I appreciate deleting my arguably alternative answer, but how about a notifications so I can provide a better one?

Comment: If you're open to another open-source sortable library, here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/veyaverafi/1/edit?html,output) using [tag:rubaxa-Sortable].

Comment: @DanDascalescu [feature requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) and  [discussions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info) goes in [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @TJ: I'm [well aware of the stringent policies against features to notify users of Q&A deletion](http://stackapps.com/questions/5015/watch-my-content). I was asking Bill for a courtesy personal notification. Unfortunately I made a typo, a extra 's', which might have tripped you.